# In Mac OS ,Postgres after changing data folder location . Unable to start Postgres database . it doesnt give any error

Tags: postgresql, mac

I'm trying to use Postgres on a Mac. After changing the location of the data folder, postgres didnt start. It doesnt give any error message.

I've copied the data folder from another location, and I've tried running

```
./pg_ctl -D location -l logfile start
```

from the directory where pg_ctl is located. It gives the message `Server Started`, but when i check using `ps -ef | grep postgres`, no PID is returned. I wonder if on MacOS X, it's necessary to run initdb again on a Mac - in Windows we can easily change the data folder and it works in any location. Please help me.

Comment: The error messages should be in `logfile`. What's in it?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Reply.. I checked the logfile and it is giving error "data folder has wrong Ownership"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message "*data folder has wrong ownership*", the problem is that the copy was made in a way that doesn't retain ownership and permissions.

To avoid that, you may use `cp -rp` command in a Terminal window to copy the data folder, if you still have it:

```
cp -rp /path/to/old-data /path/to/new-data
```

If the old data directory is lost, the ownership in the new one could be fixed with:

```
  chown -R postgres /path/to/new-data
```

You may also need to ensure proper permissions with:

```
  chmod -R go-rwx /path/to/new-data
```